# How to define an algebraic data type

Tags: haskell

Apologies for another question, I think I shall re-phrase my original question here as this is probably a pretty simple thing to do:

If i had a language which i wanted to create, like so:

```
A B <something> C
```

this would mean only an input like: A B .... C would be valid.

In contrast, B A ..... would not be valid.

Is there any easy way to define a constructor such as 'B' must always occur after 'A'? I have only ever seen the A | B type of constructor 'A or B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
-- file Temp.hs
module Temp where
data C = C1 | C2 | C3
data B = B1 Int | B2 String | B3
data A a = MkA B a C
```

This compiles fine with `ghc -c Temp.hs` - you can't use `data` statements in `ghci`, that's one of the limitations of `ghci`.

So, here I'm defining three data types:

- `C`, which has three constructors which take no arguments: `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`.  Each of these is a value of type `C`
- `B`, which has constructors

  - `B1` which wraps a `Int` value, so `B1 3` and `B1 544` are values of type `B`
  - `B2` which wraps a `String` value, so `B2 "hello"` and `B2 "world"` are values of type B
  - `B3` is a simple argument-less constructor, so `B3` is a value of type B.
- `A a` which is a polymorphic data type - for every type `a`, `A a` is also a data type.  It has one constructor, `MkA` which takes

  - a value of type `B`

    value of type `a`

    and a value of type `C`

  and creates a value of type `A a`.  So, for instance

  - `MkA B3 True C1` is of type `A Bool`
  - `MkA (B1 30) "Foo" C3` is of type `A String`

Comment: I get an error: *Main> A B a C

<interactive>:1:3: Not in scope: data constructor `B'

<interactive>:1:5: Not in scope: `a'

<interactive>:1:7: Not in scope: data constructor `C'

Comment: I dont quite get the A a declaration of the data

Comment: Thanks- I think that's going to give me something to work with! I shall comment here later how I get on. ps that does compile fine on ghci

Comment: could I just ask one small thing? If i wanted a function to return a string which contained "<" or ">", eg "<test>" how would i do that?

Comment: @user997112: Sounds like a good candidate for another question - esp, since you're short on detail (what are the arguments, etc).